# Fail instead of Warning when no hosts are matched

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

when you don't have any hosts in inventory, when running playbook there is only warning:

```
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
```

Is there a way to make that Error instead of Warning?

I find out that there is this parameter in ansible.cfg:

```
[inventory]
unparsed_is_failed = True
```

but it will only return error when there is no inventory file which you are trying to use. It didn't look into content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is:

1. Create the playbook "main.yml" like:

```
---
# Check first if the supplied host pattern {{ RUNNER.HOSTNAME }} matches with the inventory
# or forces otherwise the playbook to fail (for Jenkins)
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - "{{ jsonfilename }}"
  tasks:
    - name: "Hostname validation | If OK, it will skip"
      fail:
        msg: "{{ RUNNER.HOSTNAME }} not found in the inventory group or hosts file {{ ansible_inventory_sources }}"
      when: RUNNER.HOSTNAME not in hostvars

# The main playbook starts
- hosts: "{{ RUNNER.HOSTNAME }}"
  vars_files:
    - "{{ jsonfilename }}"

  tasks:
    - Your tasks
...
...
...
```

2. Put your host variables in a json file "var.json":

```
{
    "RUNNER": {
        "HOSTNAME": "hostname-to-check"
    },
    "VAR1":{
        "CIAO": "CIAO"
    }
}
```

3. Run the command:

```
ansible-playbook main.yml --extra-vars="jsonfilename=var.json"
```

You can also adapt this solution as you like and pass directly the hostname with the command

```
ansible-playbook -i hostname-to-check, my_playbook.yml
```

but in this last case remember to put in your playbook:

```
hosts: all
```

Answer (score 2):

> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

Q: ***"Is there a way to make that Error instead of Warning?"***

A: Yes. It is. Test it in the playbook. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - fail:
        msg: "[ERROR] Empty inventory. No host available."
      when: groups.all|length == 0

- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Playbook started
```

gives with an empty inventory

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "[ERROR] Empty inventory. No host available."}

---

Example of a project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
└── pb.yml

0 directories, 3 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
inventory = $PWD/hosts
```

```bash
shell> cat hosts
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - fail:
        msg: "[ERROR] Empty inventory. No host available."
      when: groups.all|length == 0

- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
         msg: Playbook started
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit
localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [fail] **********************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "[ERROR] Empty inventory. No host available."}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Q: ***"Still I am getting a warning: [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, ..."***

A: Feel free to turn the warning off. See [LOCALHOST_WARNING](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#localhost-warning).

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_LOCALHOST_WARNING=false ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [fail] **********************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "[ERROR] Empty inventory. No host available."}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: my hosts.ini dont have any hosts:
[all]

[all:vars]

and i am running it like this (with your task to fail):
ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini playbook.yml
and still i am getting warning:
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

Comment: Feel free to turn the warning off. See [LOCALHOST_WARNING](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#localhost-warning).

Comment: but still it didn't fail even with:
    - fail:
        msg: "Empty inventory. No host available."
      when: groups.all|length == 0